# JQuery DatePicker suddenly breaks (Nov 2015)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

So on this page... https://media.norquest.ca/ace/math/fs/scheduler.html
what's supposed to happen is you click the Start Date or End Date box, the widget pops up and you select a date.  This has been working perfectly for over a year.

What's happening today, suddenly, is you click on the Start Date or End Date box and nothing happens.  The widget is suddenly not responding.

Before I spend hours reading documentation, could somebody please have a look at the page code (below) and tell me if anything's out of whack with my calls?  It's the first time I've used JQuery components so I'm hoping something's wrong that will be obvious to experienced eyes.

```
<head>
<title>Flash Scheduler</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="scheduler.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#startdate" ).datepicker();
});

$(function() {
  $( "#enddate" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

</head>
```

Thanks for your time!
JF

Comment: *"Before I spend hours reading documentation"* Before we do the same, can you look at your console? There's nothing in the code you have provided that would cause this particular problem.

Comment: Also, you're including jQuery twice. One of the two can be removed. The two `$(function (){...});` can be combined. the two `$("#someid")` can be combined. None of these things however would cause the problem you are having.

Comment: The console has a complaint, which I don't remember seeing ever before, about how I'm requesting an insecure script.  (It says that scheduler.html was loaded through https and so the script request has been blocked.)

This reminds me that the college just moved this stuff over to a new server, and so maybe settings there need to be tweaked.  I'll look into that.  Cheers.

Comment: well there's your problem. :) https pages can't load http assets.

Comment: Conclusion: on our new media server, everything(?) loads through https and so the JQuery components were getting blocked.  I changed the three JQuery URLs to be https instead of http, while thinking "please, let it be this simple", and it looks like we're back in business.

Thanks, Kevin, and anyone else who looked at this.

Answer (score 2):

A recent infrastructure change at our college was behind this - the server where scheduler.html was stored began loading content through https instead of http.  As a result, the three JQuery URLs were being blocked.

Changing every instance of http:// to https:// (and then clearing Chrome's cache so it would actually run the updated file) seems to have got things running again.

Comment: Note that `//` would have worked too (omitting the `http(s)?` part) which would future proof it just in case it was ever swapped back to http.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that either.  :)  Cheers.